# Social login(facebook) with Django Rest Framework always return Invalid Token

Tags: django, facebook, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework, python-social-auth

I build my login through this [tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/django/integrate-oauth-2-into-django-drf-back-end). I try make a login by facebook on endpoint `.../social/facebook/`, and always, a receive this json response:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "token": "Invalid token",
        "detail": "400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/me?access_token=EAATf9P6TS9YBAOWem3RUZAIaUF5H6p67NfcUlSHx9JuQUBZBZBEIb6jaYQERjfB5a0QzKV0Op7FrNe0ZCZANlozR3YPExI8AarGoL9y5PKSbBRlwThDq5OyAruncW7rdMMsQLt48Uzak6kdMz4ZAJTJElKcynM0OOoPkZC6ZCoVJiRxOZCPWUkxqhhEZB6Th5TVuEZD&appsecret_proof=7ea0621354a3de8cde89cd288443f091634d3b8ab73e1ea93f6a58d1867d17bd"
    }
}
```

My json **post** is:

```
{
    "access_token": "EAATf9P6TS9YBAOW****"
}
```

Here is my code:
My settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    # libs for SignUp in API
    'social_django',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
        'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
        'register.backends.EmailBackend',
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = '137214324***'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = '*****'

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']

for key in ['GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY',
            'GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET',
            'FACEBOOK_KEY',
            'FACEBOOK_SECRET']:
    exec("SOCIAL_AUTH_{key} = os.environ.get('{key}', '')".format(key=key))

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = ['email', 'profile']

SOCIAL_AUTH_ADMIN_USER_SEARCH_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'email']

SOCIAL_AUTH_USERNAME_IS_FULL_EMAIL = True

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',  # <- this line not included by default
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

My views and my serializer, I follow this [file](https://github.com/coriolinus/oauth2-article/blob/master/views.py)

I defined the backends, the variables for facebook, it's missing anyone variable?
The keys are correct.

I am doing my request the right correct?
My settings is right?
I dont know why the facebook is can't login.

Comment: oauth2 is often a ```"Authorizations": "Bearer: 'the_token'"``` in your request header

Comment: and the body? will send empty?

Comment: you're trying to get the token or to make a post somewhere you need the token you already have?

Comment: oh my bad, you're trying to get the user token sending an access token, that's right?

Comment: Yes, I want the token for my backend, using the access_token from facebook. basically I want create a user in my backend using the access_token from Facebook

Comment: well are you sure the token is actually good? can you test it somewhere?

Comment: I get this token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken. I try this token in another lib.

Comment: Yes, the token are correct, I tested right now and it's works in another lib.

Comment: any luck with this question? I am currently stuck on it

Comment: Any luck? I'm having the same issue. I'm using rest-social-auth package.

Answer (score 0):

yes im having the same problem. posting without appsecret_proof works but i cant figure out how to remove it in django social

fixed:

went to env/lib/site-packages/social-core/facebook.py and commented the if statement in line 71